# check website is valid or not through python

Tags: python, url

I have 1000 website list to check weather its exist or not but my code is showing all correct which is starting with https://  here is below my code

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from urllib.error import URLError, HTTPError

req = Request("http://stackoverflow.com")
try:
    response = urlopen(req)
except HTTPError as e:
    print('The server couldn\'t fulfill the request.')
    print('Error code: ', e.code)
except URLError as e:
    print('We failed to reach a server.')
    print('Reason: ', e.reason)
else:
    print ('Website is working fine')
```

Comment: Can you show an URL where it shows ok and it shouldn't ? Because if I use `"http://stackoverfl.com"` it shows `We failed to reach a server.
Reason:  [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [python request library](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/).

If you do `response = requests.get('http://stackoverflow.com')` and then do `response.status_code`, you should get 200. But if you try for site that is not available, you should get `status_code` as `404`. You can use status_code in your case.

More on status codes: [Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status).

Comment: But the problem anything which is starting from https is giving ok like https://example.com/this is not a valid website but it saying ok this is more confusing let me know what would be the best solution for this

Comment: I'm getting 404 for https://example.com/this when I run it with the code that I shared above because as you said it doesn't exist. But I'm getting 200 for https://example.com because it exists. That's why I recommended the status code method as it will not give you ok (200 status code) in case the link doesn't exist.